# Why does my code work on the Simulator but not my iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKFieldNode (an electric field) being simulated in my game. The field works perfectly in the simulator, but when I run it on my iPhone 6 Plus, nothing happens - its as if there is no field.

Here's the code that makes the field (it's a member variable of SKScene):

```
    let orbiterField = SKFieldNode.electricField()
```

Here's the code that adjusts some parameters (it's in didMoveToView):

```
    orbiterField.strength = 0
    orbiterField.categoryBitMask = FieldCategory.OrbiterField.rawValue
    orbiterField.falloff = Float(orbiterFieldFalloff)

    let orbiter = childNodeWithName("Orbiter") as! SKSpriteNode
    orbiter.addChild(orbiterField)
```

I know I'm setting the field strength to zero. That's okay though, because when something happens in my game, the field's strength is changed. Here's the code that changes it:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(amountOfTimeFieldExists * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) , dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.numberOfFieldOrbsActive--
                self.orbiterField.strength = self.numberOfFieldOrbsActive != 0 ? Float(self.orbiterFieldStrength) : 0
            }
```

I also tried setting the strength to a non-zero value in didMoveToView, but that didn't change anything.

Finally, I tried printing "SKFieldNode.description()". When running on the (iPhone 6 plus) simulator, this is what I get:

[image]

However, when running it on my iPhone 6 plus, this is what I get:

[image]

Can someone please help me out? Its fine if you don't have an answer, I would even appreciate someone suggesting a way I can try debugging the problem. Anything would help. I have no idea what to try and have spent quite a while on this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running the same iOS on simulator and device?

Comment: @sangony Yes, iOS 8.3

Comment: @sangony Any suggestions on what I should do? Even a suggestion on how I can try debugging will be useful!

Comment: @dfgdfg Are you running the same model on simulator and device? Say, simulator iPhone 6 Plus and device iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: I suggest you start from the beginning. Take a clean project and only add the SKFieldNode. Run it and see what happens.

Comment: Are you doing any work with multiple threads? If so you could have a race condition that only happens on the device. I suggest you try to reproduce this issue in a small sample project and see if you still have the issue. Also I recommend you delete the app and clean the build folder in your project. In my case on a very rare occasion some of my builds result in odd physics bugs and the only way to fix is to do what I just said above.

Comment: Have you reset your iPhone simulator?